# Convert multi line string into a multidimensional array?

Tags: c#

I have a string like this:

```
Option1: Value1
Option2: Value2
Option3: Value3
```

I am trying to put this into a multidimensional array so that I can then lookup the values depending on what I put for 'Option', it will return the value.

So far I have this which will put each line into the array:

```
string[] Header = Headers.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

I am unsure how to split this into a 2 dimensional array so that it will split the line based on the colon delimiter?

How can I then perform a lookup? for example in PHP I would use the varible: `$Header['Option2']` in order to return the value for "Option2".

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add to your question an example of the output you desire.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can construct the lookup dictionary entirely with LINQ:

```
var dictionary = text.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None)
          .Select(line => line.Split(':'))
          .ToDictionary(lineParts => lineParts[0], lineParts => lineParts[1]);
```

Explanation on what it does in simple code:

```
var lines = text.Split(new []{Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None); //split the string in lines
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var line in lines)
{
    var lineParts = line.Split(':'); //split line to parts with : as delimiter
    var key = lineParts[0]; //first part is the key
    var value = lineParts[1]; //second part is the value
    dictionary.Add(key, value);
}
```

Now you can simply lookup like this:

```
var value = dictionary["Option2"];
```

Comment: Although this is probably the way I would have approached this, it is not what the OP asked for

Comment: Style question: did you mean to put the `.` at the end of the preceding line rather than before the method name? I've not seen that done before and if I'm honest, I hate it!

Comment: Oh also, though OP doesn't specify clearly, you probably need to `Trim` the value.

Comment: @DavidG sorry, quick formatitng, I actually prefer the other too :-) . But some devs actually prefer this format (colleagues at my job), as it shows the expression has to continue on the next line.

Comment: @DavidG I can do that part myself, I didn't include for simplicity.

Comment: @phuzi I think the reason OP asked for two-dimensional array is the fact that PHP would approach the problem this way, in C# `Dictionary` is I think the correct counterpart

Comment: Many thanks for this, I did have to add `.ToCharArray()` to the `Environment.NewLine` and the `":"`. minor details really.

Comment: And while I'm here (sorry!) I would also recommend doing `line.Split(new[] { ':' }, 1))` in case the value contains a `:`

Comment: (because what you have here doesn't actually compile...)

Comment: @DavidG - right, exactly, just wanted to post it :-) . Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray() will produce an additional empty line on Windows (as it will split by CR and LF separately), David's solution is better, I will update the answer

Comment: Updated to use string array overload :-)

Comment: I say you are still using the wrong overload. Have you checked this code works?

Comment: There was a bug `line` inestead of `lineParts`, but I fixed it in the answer. Tried now with dotnetFiddle, should be ok - https://dotnetfiddle.net/8ZQWje

Comment: Like it :-). I was assuming fully valid input in the answer, this is more user-proof

Comment: Thanks all. This has helped me big time. I was stuck thinking about PHP and would never have worked this out!